# Multiplication rule for Clifford algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, riemannian-geometry, tensors, clifford-algebras

Picture below is from 67 of Jost's *Riemannian Geometry and Geometric Analysis*, I think it is too brief for who never study Clifford algebra. So ,I have many question.

First, how to know the multiplication rule is 2.4.1 ?

Second, what is $e_ie_j=-e_ie_j$ ?  It's $e_ie_j=\delta_{ij}$ ?

Third, Are there any book about Clifford algebra and Spin structure in detail ?

[image]

Comment: [David Hestenes' work](http://geocalc.clas.asu.edu/) may provide a different perspective, and in some ways, a gentler on ramp.  He also has [papers on connecting to Spin groups](http://geocalc.clas.asu.edu/pdf/LGasSG.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You apply $v \otimes v = -||v||^2$ to vector $v+w$:
$$
(v+w)\otimes (v+w) = ||v+w||^2,
$$
So
$$
v \otimes v +w\otimes v+ v \otimes w +w \otimes w = -||v||^2-2(v,w)-||w||^2.
$$

For the second question $e_ie_j+e_ie_j=-2\delta_{ij}$ and $i \neq j$ gives the result.

Finally, you already know my favorite books on this topic: H. Blaine Lawson, Marie-Louise Michelsohn "Spin Geometry" and chapter 3 of Berline-Getzler-Vergne "Heat Kernels and Dirac Operators".

Comment: Yes, I have donwload the "Spin Geometry". Thanks.

Comment: How to understand the $v \otimes v = -||v||^2$, why the 2-order tensor equal to scalar ?

Comment: I think about this historically: it was observed by physicist P. Dirac that it is necessary to introduce "gamma matrices" to find a first order differential operator D s.t. D^2=Laplacian, this gamma matrices were a representation of the Clifford algebra, given explicitly in coordinates. Relations for those matrices  were exactly 2.4.2 If we clean physicists definition and give a coordinate free version it will be the definition of Clifford algebra.

Comment: We know that Laplacian is SO(n) invariant, so it is natural to expect that this new operator D (called Dirac operator) is invariant under some bigger group extending SO(n) by something like multiplication D by (-1), so that (-D)(-D) is still the Laplacian. This naive idea is implemented by construction of the group Spin(n).

Comment: What is the mean of SO(n) **invariant** of Laplacian ?

Comment: $\Delta (f \circ \phi) = (\Delta f) \circ \phi$ for any $\phi \in SO(n)$. See for example http://www.math.utk.edu/~freire/teaching/m435s11/invLaplacian.pdf (I just googled it)